# how to select 1st element from generated autocomplete list?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-chrome, selenium-rc

code is-

```
selenium.click("id=j_idt743:j_idt2340:lnkpgPtMHXProblemShowAdd");
selenium.focus("id=j_idt743:j_idt2340:txtPtMHXProblemPastMedicalHistoryName"); 
selenium.type("id=j_idt743:j_idt2340:txtPtMHXProblemPastMedicalHistoryName",s1);
selenium.typeKeys("id=j_idt743:j_idt2340:txtPtMHXProblemPastMedicalHistoryName",s1);
selenium.keyDown("id=j_idt743:j_idt2340:txtPtMHXProblemPastMedicalHistoryName","\40");
selenium.keyDown("id=j_idt743:j_idt2340:txtPtMHXProblemPastMedicalHistoryName","\13");
```

keyevents not working.......

Comment: Do you know what autocompletion plugin you are using? Is it [jQuery Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/). Knowing how the autocompletion plugin works is essential in this case. For instance, with chosen you actually have manipulate the original select that is hidden and then fire a chosen event and all is good.